# Show part of page when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have looked at questions like this but did not reach a conclusion. My question is how to show only the part of the web page that works (the monitor covers it) to the user?
And if the user scrolls, display the other component of page .
For example look at Ionic framework home page :

https://ionicframework.com

I am looking for something like this . Any idea ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can figure out when an element is in the view of the user using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), then animate the elements using Javascript when the element is in view. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver) is probably a better link for all the methods it has.